# WooCommerce send in-stock sms just for new products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I have a plugin that sends an SMS to users when the product become available.
It just sends SMS to subscribers for new products.
Products which created before installing this plugin don't benefit from the features of this plugin. 
This part of code is about sending SMS to users how enter their phone number to receive SMS when the product is available.

```php
// when product is available
public function smsInStock( $product_id ) {

    $product_id = PWooSMS()->MayBeVariable( $product_id );
    if ( is_array( $product_id ) ) {
        return array_map( [ $this, __FUNCTION__ ], $product_id );
    }

    $product           = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $parent_product_id = PWooSMS()->ProductProp( $product, 'parent_id' );
    $parent_product_id = ! empty( $parent_product_id ) ? $parent_product_id : $product_id;
    /*-----------------------------------------------------------------*/

    $post_meta = '_in_stock_send';

    if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) {
        return delete_post_meta( $product_id, $post_meta );
    }

    if ( PWooSMS()->maybeBool( get_post_meta( $product_id, $post_meta, true ) ) ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( PWooSMS()->hasNotifCond( 'enable_notif_no_stock', $parent_product_id ) ) {

        $data = [
            'post_id' => $parent_product_id,
            'type'    => 11,
            'mobile'  => WoocommerceIR_SMS_Contacts::getContactsMobiles( $parent_product_id, '_in' ),
            'message' => PWooSMS()->ReplaceTags( 'notif_no_stock_sms', $product_id, $parent_product_id ),
        ];

        if ( PWooSMS()->SendSMS( $data ) === true ) {
            //return update_post_meta( $product_id, $post_meta, 'yes' );
            //} else {
            //return delete_post_meta( $product_id, $post_meta );
        }

        return update_post_meta( $product_id, $post_meta, 'yes' );
    }
}
```

The author of plugin says that there is a problem with old products. SMS pattern does not set those products.

How can I solve this problem? Any thoughts?

Comment: First, you should always add the plugin link in your question. Ask the author of the plugin, what old products don't have or should have to work with his plugin? Also ask him what about copy/duplicate a product and create a product programmatically…